# load the videos in ipod/iphone library but always crash

Tags: iphone

I hope to load the videos in ipod/iphone library like app 'videos'.
the codes show below, but it always cause crash

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.sourceType= UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:kUTTypeMovie];
picker.delegate = self;
```

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdeb

Answer (score 0):

We need to know how you are presenting it as well and perhaps information about the line it crashed on if it happens to be in your code.  Here is an example that works for me:

```
- (void)presentVideoPicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = [self retain];
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage, nil];
    picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType =  sourceType;

    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

I send it `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`

Comment: picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie,  nil];

Comment: but there is an exception 'No available types for source 0'

Comment: but if I runned app 'Videos', my videos Did exist!